# Can I create a SWF in Flex WITHOUT using Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I am very new to the flash/flex world. I am wondering if I can create a SWF in Flex WITHOUT using Flash Builder ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `mxmlc.exe` compiles your application ([about](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/compilers_13.html)). You can compile directly using it and passing appropriate parameters.
Also you can compile using [flex ant task](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html).
And of course you can use other IDE for compiling:

- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/)
- [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org)

But all in all, all of this tools actually use mxmlc compiler (or its variations).

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! You can write ActionScript code using any editor and you can use the `mxmlc` command line tool. Refer [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html) for more on `mxmlc`. You can also use Eclipse IDE, point it to Flex SDK and do Flex development.

Adobe Flash Builder is not a must to generate .SWFs.

Answer (score 0):

A few basics:

Flash Builder is the IDE using which you'll develop applications in ActionScript (the language), taking help of the Flex framework. When you publish the application, the compiler will create an swf file which will run on Flash Player (for browser apps) and an installer file for desktop apps.

Comment: There was a mistake in my question. I wanted to know if Flash Builder / Flex Builder is *REQUIRED* to build SWF files. Can I compile it in any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed by using:

- `mxmlc` on the [command line](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html);
- Using the `mxmlc` [Ant task](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html);
- Using [flexmojos Maven plugin](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/).

FlashBuilder uses mxmlc to compile your Flex application.  Other IDEs can also build Flex applications, such as IntelliJ IDEA.